# Data isn't persisted in the database when using MongoDB with Docker volumes?

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

There is a service that uses mongodb. But when I restart computer or docker machine, no data is stored in the database.
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
Services:
...
  mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/dockerdata/db
    volumes:
        - ./dockerdata/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod
```

I tried to do database storage on the host, but it didn't help either:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
Services:
...
  mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/c/users/frol/mongodata/db
    volumes:
        - /c/users/frol/mongodata/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod
```

If you make a named volume, docker writes an error:
ERROR: for test_mongodb_1 Cannot create container for service mongodb: fa
To mount local volume: mount /c/users/frol/mongodata/db:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/d
ocker/volumes/test_mongodata/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
...
  mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/c/users/frol/mongodata/db
    volumes:
        - mongodata:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod 
volumes:
  mongodata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /c/users/frol/mongodata/db
      o: bind
```

Host - win 8.1, docker toolbox 19.03.1 installed.
Help me, please, I'm a novice. How do I make sure that the database data isn't lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first attempt would work if you just fix a simple typo in your compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
...
  mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db  # changed
    volumes:
        - ./dockerdata/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod
```

But, since `/data/db` is the default value of `MONGO_DATA_DIR`, setting it is pretty redundant.

---

But I'd prefer to use a named volume, that way the data persists but I don't have to see the "ugly" database storage folder:

```
version: "3"
services:
...
  mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
        - mongodata:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod 
volumes:
  mongodata:
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! `MONGO_DATA_DIR` was cleaned up, but unfortunately it didn't help. It doesn't work with the named volume either, the same error appears. ERROR: for mongodb  Cannot create container for service mongodb: failed to mount local volume: mount /dockerdata/db:/data/db:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_mongodata/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

Comment: `mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
         - mongodata:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
   
volumes:
  mongodata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ./dockerdata/db:/data/db
      o: bind`

Comment: @Olga Try it with the exact docker-compose file from the bottom of my answer. Don't add the `driver`, `device`, and `type` stuff to the volumes section.

Comment: @Olga Also check that you have followed the the points 1-3 in these instructions: https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `$MONGO_DATA_DIR`; leave it at its default of `/data/db`.

```yaml
services:
  mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    # No need to specifically set $MONGO_DATA_DIR
    volumes:
      - ./dockerdata/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    # No need to override command:
```

Docker containers have a separate filesystem space from the host filesystem.  A typical setup for most databases is to have the database storage in a fixed location inside the container; for MongoDB that's the `/data/db` directory.  You can mount a named volume or filesystem path there, but the code inside the container doesn't know the difference.

If you do set environment variables like `$MONGO_DATA_DIR`, they need to reflect paths inside the container; they can't directly specify host-system paths.  (@ruohola's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62029900/10008173) works because it changes the container-filesystem path of the bind mount to match the container-filesystem path in the environment variable; the host `./dockerdata` and container `/dockerdata` paths are totally unrelated.)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. After the restart, the data is lost.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As you are defining the data dir explicitly, you need to map the same directory in the volume to persist the data

```
version: "3"
services:
...
  mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db #data directory
    volumes:
        - ./dockerdata/db:/data/db #same data directory which you defined above
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. After the restart, the data is lost.